# Hiding ASP.NET SiteMap nodes in TreeView control

Tags: asp.net, treeview, sitemap

I have a SiteMap with All my nodes. I'm using a TreeView control which is linked to the SiteMap for navigation. Now I would like to hide certain nodes from appearing on the TreeView. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible. The way we do it is to add a custom "IsPhantom" attribute to the nodes we don't want shown in the sitemap (and in various other places too):

```
<siteMapNode url="~/Welcome.aspx" title="Welcome" description="" isPhantom="true" />
```

Then in the sitemap control, use the following code to remove nodes that have the "IsPhantom" attribute:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TreeView1.TreeNodeDataBound += new TreeNodeEventHandler(TreeView1_TreeNodeDataBound);              
    SiteMapSource.Provider = this.CurrentProvider;
}

protected void TreeView1_TreeNodeDataBound(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    SiteMapNode thisMapNode = (SiteMapNode)e.Node.DataItem;
    TreeNode parentTreeNode = e.Node.Parent;

    if (thisMapNode["isPhantom"] != null && thisMapNode["isPhantom"].ToLower().Equals(bool.TrueString.ToLower()) && parentTreeNode != null)
        parentTreeNode.ChildNodes.Remove(e.Node);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what criteria? If you only want to hide specific single nodes, subscribe to the NodeDataBound event of the TreeView and set the whole item (node) to Visible=false.

If you need to do this in a better way and provide more flexibility, I would advise that you implement your own SiteMapProvider. Then you can have a property ShowInNavigation for each sitemap node, and would be able to set that when constructing your sitemap.

Comment: Basically I want to show 3 menu items ie.

Users
Creare User

I want to include "Edit User" to the sitemap but not on the TreeView.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want.