# Use custom sitemap attribute as treeview node value

Tags: c#, treeview, sitemap

I have added a custom attribute field `PageID` in my web.sitemap. I am trying to display my sitemap in a TreeView and I would like to use that field as the value for the tree nodes. I receive the following error:

> Could not bind to the 'PageID' property (specified by ValueField) while data binding TreeView. Please check the Bindings fields.

How do I set the TreeNode value to the custom attribute value from my sitemap?

**web.sitemap**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode  url="~/" title="Home" PageID="0">
    <siteMapNode url="" title="Security" PageID="1">
      <siteMapNode url="~/PageSecurity" title="Page Security" PageID="2"/>
      <siteMapNode url="~/UserSecurity" title="User Security" PageID="3"/>
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

**aspx file**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:TreeView ID="MenuTreeView" CssClass="SecurityTree" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" ExpandDepth="0" OnSelectedNodeChanged="MenuTreeView_SelectedNodeChanged">
        <DataBindings>
            <asp:TreeNodeBinding NavigateUrl="" TextField="title" ValueField="PageID"/>
        </DataBindings>
    </asp:TreeView>
        <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with the answer to a somewhat similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/776723/266592), I was able to finally get this working.

I removed the ValueField from my binding `<asp:TreeNodeBinding NavigateUrl="" TextField="title"/>` and then I set it manually in the code behind.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MenuTreeView.TreeNodeDataBound += new TreeNodeEventHandler(MenuTreeView_DataBound);
}

protected void MenuTreeView_DataBound(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    SiteMapNode thisMapNode = (SiteMapNode)e.Node.DataItem;
    if (thisMapNode["PageID"] != null)
    {
        e.Node.Value = thisMapNode["PageID"];
    }
}
```

I now have a page that displays my SiteMap as a tree, and in my SelectedNodeChanged event `MenuTreeView.SelectedValue` correctly has my custom PageID.